# Why doesnt Instagram show which people saw the stories in some accounts?

Tags: instagram

Suddenly and with no apparent change, Instagram stopped showing me which people saw the stories in some accounts. Is there a way to revert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They now show you who saw the story only for the first 24 hours. After that there is no way. This was caused with the latest update.

Comment: apparently some accounts updated first than others